# Slf4j library exclude log4j for Sonatype security vulnerability

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j, sonatype

In our Sonatype scan for security vulnerability, we are getting log4j:1.2.17 as a security threat. It seems log4j is coming as part of slf4j-log4j12, a library that we are using in our code. I was thinking to exclude log4j in the pom.xml, so it will be something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Compiling and running the project, it seems to be working fine. I am just wondering what would be the side effect of excluding the library like it? Are we going to get run-time errors? Any information in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: The effect will most likely be that all loggers that use log4j2 will no longer create any log messages in the slf4j logging system.

Comment: The sonatype vulnerability issue is only with log4j (version 1 one the library), log4j2 does not have the vulnerability issues and we are trying to use that. In the pom file I am adding the dependency to log4j2:


   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.14.1</version>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly same issue. It is not generating any runtime error.
My dependency on pom like this

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is very similar to our pom file.
Are you using log4j2 instead (since log4j2 does not have the sonatype vulnerability)?